# Creation of one-off membership creates a completed payment too

Tags: civimember, civisepa

Our CiviCRM system (CiviCRM 5.58.1) uses Civi Membership as well as the CiviSEPA extension (SEPA Direct Debit version 1.8.0 with CiviSEPA Payment Processor version 1.1.0) to process payments.
The system provides a public online form (CiviCRM contribution page) where people can create a one-off membership for themselves. When this membership is created in the system, at the same time a payment with status "Completed" is also created. Which seems wrong.

Later, the new member actually pays, and a script I wrote would fetch this payment from the bank statement and create it in CiviCRM via API. So now, in the GUI, the membership shows two completed payments instead of one. And, most importantly, the membership duration doubles because two payments exist. Which is wrong.
This only affects one-off memberships, recurring memberships are fine.

I only found this other issue about the same topic, but without solution: https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepapp/issues/5

Can anyone give me a hint as to why this might happen? Does someone work closely with the CiviSEPA extension and could point me to the code responsible for this functionality?

I understand that the CiviSEPA extension [does not fully support membership payments yet](https://docs.civicrm.org/civisepa/en/latest/), but if I can fix this problem, this could be a step towards a more complete payment processing available for CiviCRM :)

Edit: This may relate to https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.sepapp/issues/18

Comment: Could you indicate which versions of CiviCRM and CiviSEPA you are using? Also can you describe if the public online form is CiviCRM contribution page or something else? In general, creating a one-off SEPA-Mandate should create a contribution with the "pending" status. Once you close the SEPA group it would become "in progress" until you mark the group as received which should finally set the payment's status to "completed".